# using NSStepper control, I am able to click after max and then have to decrement same number of clicks to decrement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Perhaps a confusing title but let me explain the issue through steps:
I have a custom style NSStepper control.  If I increment up to the point of my setMax the value will reach max as expected.  I can then keep clicking increment and the value of course does not increment.

However if I wanted to decrement from this point I need to click the decrement button on the control the same number of times I incremented past the max.  The value will only decrement when I have decremented to this point.

Make sense?

Ideas on solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Bindings for the value? I'm not sure if I remember this right, but I seem to recall that mixing manual min/max settings with bound value (or vice-versa) can cause this.

Comment: i am indeed... thanks Joshua I think thats the route to look into